# Cycle through all rows in MySQL using foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im creating a function that cycles through all the rows of a MySQL database, then populates a bunch of anchor tags with specific data pertaining to the then current id Its on. My problem is that it will only populate the first tag with the information, and no others after it according to what row it should be on. The code will hopefully better explain this.

```
    public function getLinks() {
        $output = "";

        $data = $this->_db->get('SELECT *', 'shutins', array('id', '>', 0));

        echo $data->count(); // Currently returns 2

        for($i = 1; $i < ($data->count() + 1); $i++) { // Set the count to 3 to make sure it should continue
            $this->find($i); // Gets the first row only
            $output .= "<a href=\"shutin.php?id={$this->data()->id}\" class=\"link\"><span>{$this->getName()}</span> <img class=\"next\" src=\"img/next.png\" width=\"20\"/></a>";
            $i++; // Doesn't seem to increment then start again
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

If you need to see more of my code files, Im happy to provide them.

Comment: So what specifically is your question? What are you having problems with?

Comment: It currently is only giving me the first row of data, when I need to also access every other row to populate a list.

Comment: OK.  Perhaps you should update your post to reflect this. It is not obvious what your question is unless someone reads the comment thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are double incrementing your `$i` variable. The third "parameter" of a for loop is statements to execute **after** each iteration. Your first loop will have `$i` as 1, then when it starts the second iteration `$i` will be three. It will check your condition (`$i < ($data->count() + 1)`) which will be false and the loop will end.

Side note; the second "parameter" of the loop is for statements to be run (and checked) at the **beginning** of each iteration. A more efficient way of writing the loop will be:

```
for($i = 1, $count = $data->count() + 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

This is because the count and addition performed to populate the `$count` variable only happens once, not for every iteration in the loop.

Comment: I originally didn't have the second `$i++;` and it still didn't increment properly. I had it echo out the current `$i` and it still shows its only on the 1st loop.  I was also unaware I can declare more than one parameter in a for loop.

Comment: Are you calling `$this->find()` when you should be calling `$data->something()` ?

Comment: `$this->find()` gets all the data for the current user id.

Comment: Replacing my for loop for the one you showed actually fixed it, it now iterates through all the rows properly.

Comment: It might have been something to do with `$data->count()` running on each iteration. Without seeing the rest of the code it's difficult to tell.

Comment: My PHP is still at a fairly beginner level so Im still learning a lot. Thank you tho. it now works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the `$i` variable two times in the loop. Remove the 
`$i++; // Doesn't seem to increment then start again` from your loop

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $data->count(); $i++) {  // You can use "<=" instead of ($data->count() + 1) to make it simple

    $this->find($i); // Gets the first row only
    $output .= "<a href=\"shutin.php?id={$this->data()->id}\" class=\"link\"><span>{$this->getName()}</span> <img class=\"next\" src=\"img/next.png\" width=\"20\"/></a>";

}
```

Comment: I sometimes forget my operands. But the problem was mostly it wouldn't increment properly the first time, so I tried to do it again, to no avail, but now I have it working.